# Turn a Comma Delimited String to a List of Strings with Single Quotes

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a string like this:

```
'111,222,333,444'
```

What I want to do is to turn it into something like this:

```
'111','222','333','444'
```

I can write a function to split the string into a temp table and loop through each row to add quotes. But I don't really want to use a cursor to do this. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could you not just use REPLACE to replace each , with a ','?

This assumes the string has the initial and final single quotes in them.

```
REPLACE(TheString,  ',', ''',''')
```

If not, you could just add them.

```
'''' + REPLACE(TheString,  ',', ''',''') + ''''
```